trying to the solve the equation for the metal hydride hydrogen compression from one of the research paper and understand the unit of the equations
The study of metal hydrides involves the storage of hydrogen in solid-state compounds, which is governed by thermodynamic principles. The Pressure-Concentration-Temperature (PCT) curve is crucial for understanding the relationship between hydrogen pressure, hydrogen concentration in the metal, and the temperature of the system. The zero-dimensional model represents the system as a single representative point, simplifying the calculation of the amount of hydrogen stored at specific conditions (pressure and temperature).
This process typically involves applying models for hydrogen solubility and hydriding kinetics in metal alloys, with the goal of calculating the hydrogen concentration and storage capacity at a given temperature and pressure.
I have used the following research paper for performing the calculations and I was using the following equation to predict the concentration of the hydrogen in PCT curve at a point before equilibrium.
where, $\gamma$ represents the activity coefficient.
$\Delta H $ represents the heat of solution of the hydrogen
, $\Delta S$ represents the entropy change
, $V_H$  represents the specific molar volume of the hydrogen
A is the coefficient , R and T represents the gas constant and temperature respectively.
$C_{H}=AP^{\gamma/2}\exp{\frac{-\gamma V_{H} P}{RT}}\exp{\frac{\Delta H_{s}}{RT}}$
What I am trying to understand the unit for the equation, it looks like the exponential terms will be unitless and the coefficient A is also unitless/dimensionless. Now it looks that the concentration unit that looks like atm , which doesn't looks like the correct dimension and doesn't make sense. Can anyone assist me in understand , cause the paper tells us that it is in hydrogen atom/ metal atom ratio. If this, then how can we convert hydrogen atom/ metal atom to the moles or grams of hydrogen per 1 Kg of metal ($LaNi_5$)
link:https://doi.org/10.1016/0360-3199(94)90097-3
please assist me in understanding the equations and units of the equation and also, and what term means.

Yes, $C_H$ is just the atom ratio ($M/H$ in fig. 1), and $P$ is in atm in fig. 1, so $P^{\gamma /2}$ is just a lazy way of writing $(P/ \pu{1 atm})^{\gamma/2}$.
For conversion of the atomic ratio, note that it is also a mole ratio. Then convert the moles to mass using the molar masses of H ($\pu{1 g/mol}$) and $\ce{LaNi5}$ ($\pu{432.36 g/mol}$).

Thank you so much, that's what confused me, cause I was like why "atm", but now I understood, it is basically a ratio of pressure based on 1 atm pressure correct!

Thank you, so I was just wondering that when we combine the Cp for both the hydrogen and metal hydride, we can use the formula for the mixtures of specific heat for hydride and hydrogen. I have provided the link for the reference.https://thermtest.com/thermal-resources/rule-of-mixtures

That seems to be question not related to the paper?  But in any case the hydrogen in a metal is not really a mixture, so I don't think that relationship would hold.

Yes, I was trying to solve the specific heat for the metal hydride(LaNi5H6) for heat calculations and that's how I was planning to do the calculations

Hello, I found a paper which has the values for the specific heat for the LaNi5H6 for various temperatures and I was wondering if taking the average values for the specific heat would assist in solving at that temperature range.

You didn't accept my answer?

I don't understand your newest question. Averaging values over a temperature range seems reasonable.
